# Function not recognized by Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been messing around with Javascript recently and I'm still a beginner. I've been trying to build a simple program which finds a specified string inside the text entered into the text field using regular expressions, but for some reason when I click the "Find" button it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: find is not a function
    onclick http://192.168.178.20:62126/JavaScript/Findy/index.html:1
index.html:1:1
```

Here's my code:

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Findy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" id="toFind" placeholder="What do you wanna find?">
      <input type="button" id="find" onclick="find()" value="Find"></input>
      <textarea name="textToSearch" id="textToSearch" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
function find() {
  var text=document.getElementById("textToSearch").value;

  var word=document.getElementById(toFind).value;
  var myRegex=/word/;

  console.log(text.match(myRegex));
}
```

Comment: In the scope of the `onclick` attribute, `find` is the button with `id="find"` and not the global `find` variable. `onclick` **attributes** are awful. Use the  `addEventListener` method instead.

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: @Quentin I think you closed this prematurely. There are some other issues with that code.

Comment: @Andy — That's the issue the question is about.

Comment: OP: https://jsfiddle.net/xev41s23/1/

Answer (score -2):

You need to add a `<script>` tag below where the `find()` function is called.

Second solution is to add `async` attribute to `<script>` tag

Comment: No. If the problem was that the function defined in the script was not defined at the time the function was called then (a) You'd need to make it available **sooner** and not **later** and (b) the error would be a reference error saying that `find` was not defined (the error says it is defined but is not a function).